# Git submodules are not shown as folder in parent in TFS

Tags: git, git-submodules, tfs-2015

I have a `Git` repo that contains another repo as `submodule` in `TFS`. The submodule was added with this command:

```
git submodule add https://myurl/base base
```

When I clone the parent repository my local copy works fine. I can see the submodule and can access it.

But in `TFS 2015` my submodule is not accessible from the parent. If i click `base` (which should be a folder or a link to the submodule) i only see a checksum, it looks like this:

[image: TFS Screenshot]

What am I missing? Or is this a problem with TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A submodule's content is not stored in the "parent" repo[1].  TFS doesn't follow the submodule link to fetch the content.  You can say it's a limitation of TFS (and AFAIK any git-hosting software), but not an unexpected one in my opinion[2].  I never looked closely enough to be sure, but I would assume the hash it displays is the commit hash at which you would find the excluded content in the submodule repo.

---

[1] : Locally in your work tree, it looks mostly like everything is in your repo - because that's the illusion submodules create by having your work tree span multiple repos.  But the parent repo database - the part that's sent to a remote like TFS - contains only a reference to the other repo.

[2] : In general it can't even be assumed that the remote would have access to fetch from an arbitrary "other repo" that might be listed as a submodule.